# Maven GPG plugin not signing sources and javadoc jars

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, gnupg, sonatype

I'm attempting to release my project's artifacts to Sonatype using Maven. I'm using the Maven GPG plugin to sign the artifacts, but it's not signing the sources and javadoc jars (just the main jar), which is required by Sonatype. Here's what I think are the relevant parts of my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Is there any way to tell it to sign these others jars too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These changes to the pom solved the problem:

```
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Comment: So, in short: remove the phase for doc and source plugins.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain why it was the problem?

Comment: Thank you for sharing this here. I had a similar problem and it was an order issue. `attach-sources`, `attach-javadoc` and `maven-gpg-plugin` were all defined to run during the verify phase.
I have moved the `attach-*` tasks to the `package` phase and it worked fine for me.