# Maven GPG Plugin 1.4 works fine, but 1.5 does not work

Tags: maven, code-signing, gnupg

I am currently trying to sign my packaged jars etc. with the maven GPG Plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html).

I found on several sites (for example here: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven ) the hint, that one could do this with the following code in once pom.xml:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>sign</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Unfortunately, if I do this, and run maven package gpg:sign, it stops when trying to sign. If I add `<version>1.4</version>` (like in [Maven GPG plugin not signing sources and javadoc jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920081/maven-gpg-plugin-not-signing-sources-and-javadoc-jars)), it works fine. Normally, it uses version 1.5, and if I specify that it should use this version, it does not work. Does anyone know what the reason of this behavoir is, and how I need to configure the maven-gpg plugin to run correctly with version 1.5?

Comment: The question is: What do you mean by `does not work`? Do you get errors? Put in a log output of the occured error etc.

Comment: No, unfortunately not, it just stops when I try to sign. So when I run mvn package gpg:sign, it does nothing after saying `[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (default-cli) @ kopeme-core ---` (and then I need to cancel the process, it does not end).